# Showing that $\Bbb R^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Using the definition

> $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ is connected iff it cannot be written as the union of two disjoint non empty opens $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb R^n$,

how would you prove that $\Bbb R^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ ?

I know it is "path connected" by the standard definition of path connected, but in the definition that we use that does not imply connected.

Comment: How come?        .....

Comment: What does the assertion “the definition that we use that does not imply connected” *mean*?

Comment: Using the definition of connectivity that you wrote in your question, the statement "path connectivity implies connectivity" is true and pretty easy to prove, by applying the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Just add to the definition of path connected the condition that is also connected

Answer (score 2):

The definition you wrote **does** mean that path connected implies connected. That is, the statement

> "If $X$ is path connected, then it is connected"

is true, if we use the definition of connectedness that you wrote.

---

However, if you want to prove $\mathbb R\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is connected without resorting to the theorem above, you can still do it by sort of re-proving that theorem.

Assume that $X,Y$ are both closed, open and nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Then, as they are nonempty, there exists $x\in X, y\in Y$. Now, draw a path from $x$ and $y$, and prove that the path cannot be continuous and exist in $X$ and $Y$ at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R^2$? 
Why would two such subsets exist?

Comment: @JohnCataldo Not $\mathbb R^2$ but $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$. The idea is to prove that two such subsets do **not** exist. This by showing that the assumption that they exist contradicts that $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is path-connected.

Comment: But then you're using the theorem not path connected $\implies$ not connected. Which is the same as connected $\implies$ path connected, which is what I want to avoid because of the alternative definition that we use